# Establishing the ground truth for difficult cases when it comes to images

Tags: image-recognition, labels

I need to create some labels with `labelImg` for specific objects, but there are two main factors, which make the process of creating bounding boxes a difficult task.

- The objects of interest are small compared to the size of the image and stacked together, think like two or more rectangles stacked together.
- The quality of the image is not very good, which means that if I zoom in a very high level, the quality of the image worsens, thus I am not even able to distinguish their boundaries.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?